# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "zu" und "allzu"?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "zu" und "allzu"?
Bei "zu" meine ich natürlich die folgende Bedeutung, laut Duden:
"kennzeichnet ein (hohes oder geringes) Maß, das nicht mehr angemessen oder akzeptabel erscheint"

Z.B.

> Das Kleid scheint mir zu groß
> Das Kleid scheint mir allzu groß

> Das ist mir allzu langweilig
> Das ist mir zu langweilig

Wann würde sich man eher für das eine oder andere entscheiden?

Danke.

Comment: Dieser Frage würden ein paar Beispielsätze guttun, um dein Problem zu verdeutlichen.

Comment: "... um dein Problem allzu verdeutlichen" würde nämlich nicht funktionieren, aber das ist ja wahrscheinlich nicht deine Frage.

Comment: Ich habe zusätzliche Verdeutlichung und Beispielsätze hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"zu groß" heißt, daß eine bestimmte Grenze überschritten wurde.  "allzu groß" beinhaltet das Zugeständnis, daß es verschiedene Ansichten über die Lage einer solchen Grenze geben mag und auch eine gewisse Bereitschaft zur Akzeptanz vorhanden ist und/oder auch ausgedrückt wurde; die vorhandene Größe liege aber jedenfalls jenseits des akzeptablen, so daß die Meinungsbildung zu diesem Angebot als abgeschlossen betrachtet werden und ein anderes Angebot gemacht werden solle.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht hilft eine Übersetzung ins Englische? Ich denke *that* ist eine gute Übersetzung für *allzu*.

> Das Kleid scheint mir *zu* groß. -- The dress looks *too* big to me.

> Das Kleid scheint mir nicht *allzu* groß. -- The dress doesn't look *that* large to me.

Comment: Gehen wir davon aus, dass Deutsch die Muttersprache von OP ist, dann weiß ich nicht, ob eine Übersetzung ins Englische hilfreich ist. Bzw. eine Übersetzung die Frage sich nicht im Kreis drehen lässt.

Comment: Nein, das hilft nicht, keine Übersetzungen bitte.

Comment: @mtwde: I don't know if it's considered a factor, but translations do help English speakers sometimes. I can see where they might be considered off-topic though.

Answer (score 0):

Beide Adverbien, wenn benutzt um ein Übermaß auszudrücken, scheinen zumindest in der Richtung von Übertreibung identisch in der Anwednung zu sein. Zusätzlich kann "zu" auch Untertreibung ausdrücken. Also "zu viel" und "allzu viel" sind identisch, "allzu wenig" oder ein "allzu kleines Kleid" oder eine "allzu kurzweilige Vorstellung" aber eher ungewöhnlich.

Duden "[allzu](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/allzu)"

> in zu hohem Grade, übertrieben, übermäßig

Duden "[zu](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zu_Adverb)"

> kennzeichnet ein (hohes oder geringes) Maß, das nicht mehr angemessen oder akzeptabel erscheint

DWDS "[allzu](https://www.dwds.de/wb/allzu)"

> zu sehr, in zu hohem Grade

DWDS "[zu](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu#2)"

> in höherem oder geringerem Maß als angemessen